# mkdir command with docker

Tags: java, docker, mkdir

Inside my docker container, this command `mkdir -p -m 755 directoryName` creates a directory (Blue File) at the given path. However, outside docker, when I attempt to create a directory with the same command `mkdir -p -m 755 ContainerID:/root/.../directoryName` it seems to be creating an Executable (Green File).

This is causing trouble because with my "create directory" command i'm copying stuff to it, and the command is failing when I do it outside of docker.

This is what my full command will be, when I execute outside docker:

```
mkdir -p -m 755 ContainerID:/root/../dirName && docker cp someImage.jpg ContainerID:/root/../dirName
```

Any thoughts on how to to make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be honest, I have never heard of such mkdir syntax, referencing a different host, but in any case (even if it was supported) I would not use it. You should execute anything you want to to inside a docker container as `docker exec ContainerID mkdir -p -m 755 /root/../dirName`

If you want to put several commands inside the same docker exec call you can do it by executing `docker exec ContainerID bash -c "whatever && whatever2 && ... whateverX"`

Have in mind that these commands will be executed as the user referenced in the Dockerfile with an `USER` clause, defaulting to `root`. There are some images in which the user is set to something different, leading to permission issues while doing stuff like this. The right approach to follow would depend on whatever you want to achieve.

Hope that helps! :)